# What in Android would allow me to touch the edge of my screen while playing my game and slide over an Item screen?

Tags: java, android, uiview, view

Android has many useful tools when coming to views and screens and layouts.

Description: While playing my game (running around as a zombie bear eating humans) I would like to allow the player to access an items menu via sliding a menu from the right side/edge of the screen. Or at the least be able to access a game options menu (not game settings which would be the menu button).

What would be the best fit for description?

P.S How would I make a question like this less like a discussion and more like a straight forward programming question when I don't really know what's available to do this.

Also, if this is the case, please point me to another location to ask a question that may require a discussion.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) class.

PS I personally don't see a problem with how you have worded your question if you are looking for ideas of views/widgets you need to perform a specific function/effect.

Comment: Totally forgot about that class!

Comment: So many views/widgets I've never seen... Yea, check this one out for sure. There should be a "Humbled" badge on StackOverflow for up-voting someone else's answer when you have an answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought, and for a simple approach (this wouldn't be animated or dragged really), would be using a RelativeLayout where the portion representing the menu was initially set so that it's visibility were GONE, except for a small tab or arrow or something. When that tab/arrow is touched, the visibility of the View for the menu could be toggled to VISIBLE.

With visibility set to GONE, a view is not drawn or considered in any part of the layout pass when the screen is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate a listview with some icons and when an particular icon is selected, then figure out which one was selected and then execute some function and hide the sidebar using an animation. I've never developed a game, so I'm not too sure how far it deviates from the standard, but I wish you the best of luck :) ! If you post the source let me know would love to test your game and see how you work with the source!